# How to submit new app updates in the published app in Partner Center / Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, msix, windows-dev-center

I have an MSI installer to submit it in the Partner Center or Microsoft store. I converted my MSI installer into MSIX package format using the MSIX packaging tool.

I had already an idea of how to publish my app in the MS store using this reference: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html

However, there's a question that comes to my mind. Once I published my application in the MS store and
What if I have new updates in my app, what are the steps how to do that?

I did some research most of the results have something to do with source code.

My preferred approach is to update the app without coding configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submission process is managed through the Microsoft Partner Center dashboard, which is a web portal that allows developers to publish applications, and manage the updates of the application to allow keeping the app up to date automatically.

Once you submit updates to a published application, the updated packages will be available on average about two hours after submission (though this can sometimes take longer, especially with larger packages). Price, screenshot, or description changes take on average 16 hours to go live. Customers will receive the updated package the next time their device looks for updates, if (automatic app updates) are turned on,
or when they trigger the update by proceeding to the Windows Store and choosing (Check for updates) on the downloads. By default, automatic updates are turned on in the Microsoft Store, so users will always use the latest version of your application.

References:

1. MSIX Auto Updates https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-auto-updates.html
2. Update a public app https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/05/13/publish-or-update-a-public-app-dev-center-tip-1/
3. Mandatory updates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#mandatory-package-updates
4. Upload app packages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages